# How to add Blog link in wordpress default menu in Twenty Twelve Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have developed one new theme based on Twenty Theme and the live link is [here](http://www.photokamp.com/)
I have set a static page as home page. Now I need to add my "Blog" page to the main navigation.

I googled and did all my trials. But everything gives information of custom navigation which I know very well.

Here the case is to add the default Blog link to the main navigation.

Please help me out guys

Comment: I see your website now has a blog link, so I assume you got this working then?

Comment: yes @Simon. I got the solution myself. Its as easy as 123.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its very simple.
Create one new page called "Blog".
Go to Settings -> Reading.
Choose "Blog" in the select box "Posts page" under "Front page displays".
Click "Save Changes".

That's it.